# Let CMake not detect C++ compiler

Tags: cmake

I'm working on a C project. But others told me that they couldn't build it because they didn't have a C++ compiler.

I have no idea how to disable C++'s detection. How to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Detecting C and C++ toolchains is the default behavior for CMake. To disable this behavior, you'll need to manually enable the language. If it's project wide, you can explicitly tag the project as 'C' by using `project(projectName C)`. This information is in the CMake documentation.

Comment: I used "PROJECT (name C)". Don't know why CMake fails if I use "[C]".

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use LANGUAGES C
That also combines with the more common use

> project(projectName VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES C)